# PHP prevent image scrape

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a project that serves many images. That project also have an API that serves not only but the image links.

I would like to have a way to successfuly avoid the **scraping** of my images. I don't mind users could download each image individually but would not like that someone could scrape all images at the same time to avoid high bandwith usage.

I though using htaccess to deny direct access to image folders.
Also, thought to use in PHP (in website) to use a dynamic link to show the image (for example `loadimage.php?id=XXXXX`) so my users doesn't know the full image link.

How could I do it in API (and even in website) to prevent scraping? I though something like a token and each request will generate a new "image id", but or I'm missing something or can't figure it out how to make it work.

I know it will be impossible to have a 100% valid method to do it, but any suggestions in how to difficult it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The concept is relatively simple, you have a script that proxies the image data instead of the web server.  The parameter passed to the script can be anything to identify the image, a file name or database primary key.  The script then locates the image, and uses something like fopen to read the image data and send it to the browser. You just need to remember to respond with the correct header for the image type you are sending and to place the image location outside of the public webroot.

Comment: This could solve one of mine problems. But when using API, I can't avoid massive scrapping that script right? Maybe I'm not understanding it right.

Comment: The script can implement things like session checking or rate limiting, etc.  See the `429 Too Many Request` answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a rate limit policy.  It involves tracking how many times the images are being requested (or the number of bytes being exchanged), and issuing a (typically) `429 Too Many Requests` response when a threshold is exceeded.

Nginx has some pretty good [built-in tools](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) for rate limiting.  You mention `.htaccess` which implies Apache, for which there is also a [rate limiting module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ratelimit.html).

You could do this with or without PHP.  You could identify a URL pattern that you want rate limited, and apply the rate limit policy to that URL pattern (could be a PHP script or just a directory somewhere).

For Apache:

```
<Location ".../path/to/script.php">
    SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
    SetEnv rate-limit 400 
    SetEnv rate-initial-burst 512
</Location>
```

Or, you could write code in your PHP that writes accesses to a database, and enforces a limit based on how many accesses in a given window period.

I would not generally recommend writing your own when there are such good tools available supported in the web server itself.  One exception would be if you use several web servers in a cluster, which cannot easily synchronize rate limiting thresholds and counts across the server.

Comment: Based on your description it seems it could not make everything I would like. For example if I set the rate to 400, if I have 401 genuine users at the same time, it will output the error right? Or this error could be outputed only for images?

Comment: Correct, you can restrict by all kinds of different parameters - `*.(png|jpg)`, a specific directory (`/foo/bar/baz/`) or even a specific script only (`/directory/foobar.php`)

Comment: You can also restrict to bandwidth out (no more than 400kb/s) or number of requests (no more than 400 req/m) etc.  It's even possible to *slow* the flow rather than *stop* the flow.  With some forethought you could even exclude specific users (by IP address, login status etc) from consideration of the limits.

Comment: Flow control the way you describe is very much a solved problem.

Comment: Thanks. Will read more about that to check a way to make that only to avoid the same user to make quick requests. Since it will not be a open API (at first time) maybe I can block the requests with the use of a database and time control. Thanks for your time.

Comment: A sufficiently motivated user will easily circumvent "user based" controls on an open api.  Best to go with a global bandwidth limiting policy to avoid overages on your bandwidth while still servicing legitimate requests.